# Blog menus are being shown on two places in mobile version

Tags: php, wordpress, web, blogs

Recently, I created a [blog](http://99hax.com).
The problem is that its menus are showing up twice in mobile version. On desktop, it's working fine. I can't attach picture because of reputation so please visit this blog http://99hax.com on mobile and you can see menu in header. Below those menus, you'll see a menus button. Clicking on it will show same menus.
This blog is hosted by awardspace and I have installed wordpress in it. That's why I am not able to understand what's the problem.

Comment: Have you changed any of the CSS?  The Garfunkel theme should only display one menu at widths below 1000px.

Comment: I never dealt with files. so I haven&#39;t changed anything. And this menu problem is occurring in mobile version only.

Comment: In that case, it's probably one of the plugins. I would start by deactivating WP MashSocial Wigdet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following custom CSS was added to the site:

```
.main-menu {
display: inline-block;
}
```

That CSS overrides the `display: none;` CSS that is used to hide the main menu on smaller screens.

You can remove that CSS from the **Additional CSS** panel of the Customizer (in the dashboard navigate to Appearance > Customize)

Comment: I remember, that code was added by one of my frnd to make menus in center.
I did nothing with custom CSS you said above but I removed additional CSS from customizer. Its working fine now. *Is that enough*?

Comment: I see that you removed the CSS.  That's enough to fix the issue with two menus.

Comment: That additional CSS was written to make menus in centre but if it's creating issues then what's the other way to make menus in centre?

Comment: Centering the menu is a bit out of scope for this topic, so I recommend asking a new question or checking the theme's support forum:  https://wordpress.org/support/theme/garfunkel